# PAYPAL - Invalid Test API Credentials

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi,

I have setup a business account at Paypal, and it seems that I already have my Test API Credentials, since I can successfully retrieve them from my Sandbox accounts.

Now I am trying to make the "first call" to get an authorization token.

Here's my PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "myid"; //not the actual one
$secret = "mypass"; //not the actual one
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Accept: application/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
print_r($json);
curl_close($ch);
```

And here's the response:

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => invalid_client [error_description] => Invalid client credentials )
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks

EDIT: This login is working (I found it elsewhere):

clientId: ASF6RRBP0uTq7FnC90tpFx7vfA-Pliw8uQDjv5RZ10Y_NVspuc88pUPLN6yM
Secret: EAdx7BDKzWczDomYG2QDHu8jhaAXj4xDZLHadvL5aRfesjwo5c81zbSpRxuE

Strangely the format looks very different from mine.

I'm stuck here, cannot go any further without a token.

Comment: are you sure you using the sandbox credentials since your endpoint is Sandbox.? make sure there is no empty space between $clientid and $secret id

Comment: Use this class method for handling your payment provided by paypal.
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Comment: vimal: i retrieved my credentials from sandbox/accounts, the username is something like name-facilitator_api1.mysite.com and the pass is a hash of uppercase letters, like BHTG9GM38NQ4XGW6; there's is only a ":" between clientid and pass

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a header similar as follows:

```
"Authorization" => "Basic " . base64_encode($clientId . ":" . $clientSecret)
```

This should act the same as above.

You could write it on curl_setopt like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($clientId . ":" . $clientSecret));
```

Also, just out of curiosity, you might want to try out [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK). They have all these bells and whistles, that would keep you away from manually getting this code. It has [documentations](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki), and [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples), that would help you get started with any API fairly quickly.

Comment: wanna try it, but how do i write it in php using curl_setopt?

Comment: Updated the response accordingly

Answer (score 0):

finally i managed to get it to work

the correct credentials are a hash of 60-digit, not 16 as first seen

i had to create an app to get them

nobody told me that at paypal, not even the "merchant technical support"

hope this helps someone in the future

thanks for your answers